# Bad practice to use store in effect?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have an `InitAction` with some params like a profile id and some more data and that action can be called a couple of times with different params.

Besides there is a `LoadProfileAction` and I added an effect that is listening to `InitAction` and triggers the `LoadProfileAction`.

The problem is, that I only want to trigger the `LoadProfileAction`, if the profile id had changed compared to the previous one so I think the best(?) solution is to use `withLatestFrom` with the store in my effect and check the current profile id.

But it feels wrong to use the store in an effect because it seems to break the flux principle or isn't that true? Are there any better solutions? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this breaks principle. If you are relying on data outside of your state there are a few ways but i think Store makes the most sense. Else you run the risk of code smell in your reducers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update

Now NgRX (v12) provides its own operator for using the store inside an effect. You don't need the two `concatMap`, `of`, `withLatestFrom` solution anymore. Now you can use `concatMapFrom` from the `@ngrx/effects` library like follows:

```js
import { concatLatestFrom } from '@ngrx/effects';

...

createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(getSelectedBookDetails),
  concatLatestFrom(action => this.store.select(getSelectedBookId)),
  switchMap(([action, selectedBookId]) => this.bookService.getDetails(selectedBookId).pipe(
    map(...),
    catchError(...)
  )
);
```

#### Old answer from 2020/08/19

Bit late to answer this, but maybe it is a help for someone out there. I use NgRX almost everyday and I'd like to share my personal insights.

You can definitely use the store in your effects. You just need to import the store via the constructor (since it is part of the dependency injection tree) and then you can use it in the related effects with the `withLatestFrom` RxJS operator. If you read the official docs you will probably see a note on the [effects documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects) which says

> Note: For performance reasons, use a flattening operator in combination with withLatestFrom to prevent the selector from firing until the correct action is dispatched.

So ideally you use the store in the following way:

```js
createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(getSelectedBookDetails),
  concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getSelectedBookId))
  )),
  switchMap(([action, selectedBookId]) => this.bookService.getDetails(selectedBookId).pipe(
    map(...),
    catchError(...)
  )
);
```

Where `getDetails()` is an Angular http request and returns an Observable and `getSelectedBookId` is an NgRX selector. At least I hope you can get the idea how to use it and that it is not a problem at all to use it in an effect.

You can also be sure that the effect is executed after the reducer has been executed. [This order is guaranteed](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/162).

Comment: While this perfectly describes _how_ to access the store in effects, it doesn't answer the question whether it is bad practice.